# How to turn off rogue OneDrive video syncing

Tags: sync, onedrive, online-storage, windows-7

(I am running Windows 7.)

Yesterday I did some clean-up and moved some mp4 files from my desktop to "My Videos".  Later I got a message that my OneDrive was almost full.  Then I realized that when I had put the videos into "My Videos", they magically got put into OneDrive as well.  Deleting them from OneDrive deleted them from "My Videos" as well.  Restoring them in the Recycle Bin put them back into both places.

Right-clicking OneDrive, it appeared that this shouldn't have happened, since

- under Settings, "Let me use OneDrive to fetch any of my files on this PC" was **not** checked;
- under Auto Save, "Automatically save photos and videos to OneDrive whenever I connect a camera, phone, or other devices to my PC" was **not** checked either.

*(My answer appears below -- if someone has an alternative answer I'm all ears.)*

Comment: As you're asking about the file synchronization function of OneDrive, rather than the web interface, your question is more appropriate for [su].

Comment: @ale - Would it then be okay for me to delete this and repost it over there?

Comment: That would certainly be faster than waiting for it to be migrated.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click "My Videos".  Choose Properties --> Location.  If the location is inside OneDrive, click "Restore Default."  Click "Okay" several times.  (This appears to have fixed the problem for me.)